# Trying to convert form search into PDO query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

This was my prior code, that a SO user said was prone to injection, so I decided to try to convert it to be used with PDO.

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])) {

$q = $_POST['q'];

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' OR email LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY ID DESC");
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" name="search" />
</form>
```

This is the code I tried to insert :

```
include 'database.php';
   $pdo = Database::connect();
   $q = $_POST['q'];
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' OR email LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY ID DESC';
   if(isset($_POST['q'])) {

   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['mobile'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td width=250>';
            echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
            echo '&nbsp;';
            echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
            echo '&nbsp;';
            echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            }
   }
   Database::disconnect();
  ?>
```

The error I get is :
Notice: Undefined index: q
Warning: Division by zero

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Cause your POST request does not contain `q` index. And that's because you have no action definied for your form. Moreover, I've a big doubt about your `$sql` string escaping. Use double quotes to wrapp it instead of simple one.

Comment: You're still vulnerable to SQL injections, you need to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: @Styphon Thanks, I will try to alter my code after reading your link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because `q` does not exist, you've not posted it to the page. You should try something like this:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$q = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($q)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE :q OR email LIKE :q ORDER BY ID DESC";
    $sth = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $sth->bindParam(':q', "%{$q}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that there was a function built into php to automatically sanitize code to prevent injections, need to pick me up a php manual somewhere instead of learning from code tidbits.  For people new like me, I found this guide that explains how FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING works : http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_string.asp

Comment: @Steven Nooooooo, this does not do anything against sql injection. You need to use a prepared statement.

Comment: @Steven using filter_sanitize_string will not protect you against SQL injections. You need to use the prepared statements like I put in where you had your query before. Rather than picking up a manual or refering to w3schools, learn how to use php.net as everything is on there.

Comment: im surprised this worked, named placeholders need not to be quoted

Comment: @Ghost I thought they did if they had other characters, such as the `%` for the like?

Comment: @Styphon its supposed to be `WHERE columnname LIKE :placeholder`, then you include the wildcards inside the bound vars `->bindParam(':placeholder', "%{$var}%")`, but whatever, OP's just fine with that

Comment: So are you saying "$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE '%$q%' OR LName LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY ID DESC";     " should be : $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE '%$FName%' OR LName LIKE '%$LName%' ORDER BY ID DESC";  ?  And how do you do a bind param in PDO?

Comment: @Steven, look at my code above as to how to bind a param... it's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your query with this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' OR email LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

And you can use your code by changing your condition as

```
if(isset($q)){
     // your code
}
```

Comment: That fixed the divide by zero error, lol - but it still shows "Undefined index: q".  Why would it show undefined index, when clearly "q" points towards the results of the form submission?

Comment: Because you were not getting value within `$_POST['q']`

Comment: Thank you!  I love the fact there are so many helpful people on this site.

Answer (score 1):

> The error I get is : Notice: Undefined index: q Warning: Division by zero

That mean $_POST['q'] not defined your code should be

```
               if(isset($_POST['q'])) {

                  $pdo = Database::connect();
                   $q = $_POST['q'];
                   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' OR email LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY ID DESC';

                   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['mobile'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td width=250>';
                            echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                            echo '&nbsp;';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                            echo '&nbsp;';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            }
                   }
                   Database::disconnect();
                 }
               ?>
```

And not forget add html form

Comment: No, you will get the same `division by zero` warning because the quotes in the query are not escaped and the variable is not correctly concatenated. Double quotes would also solve this and both have the same sql injection problem as the original code.